# Once (if?) we get out of beta, do reputation-levels for privileges increase retroactively?

Tags: support, beta, reputation

Reputation levels to gain access to privileges are very different on non-beta sites. Do those levels get adjusted retroactively once a site graduates? What I mean by that is, If I have a certain privilege now that the site is in beta, will I loose it if the reputation level adjusts to a level higher than the reputation I currently have once the site graduates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beta sites are set up with some reduced reputation requirements to help bootstrap those activities that are needed to help the site function (voting, editing, closing, etc). But once the community has built up a sufficient base of avid users — i.e. when the site graduates — the reputation requirements will be restored/raised to the "normal" levels.

**Those changes *are* retro active.** If you do not have the reputation necessary to perform a task (under the new requirements), you are not *grandfathered* in. In other words, you will have to earn the reputation needed according to the new requirements.